# PhP File upload works on my phone but not my PC

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

I have the below PHP script processing my form.

Why am I not seeing the file in the specified location?

Is there something I am doing wrong with regards to the file's location?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadFile.php" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

```
<?php

    echo "Processing...<br>";

    $fileResult = "";
    if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        $fileResult .= "No File Uploaded";
        $fileResult .= "Error Code: " + $_FILES["file"]["error"];
    } else
    {
        $fileResult .= 
        "Upload:" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>" .
        "Type:" . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>" . 
        "Size:" . $_FILES["file"]["size"] . "<br>" .
        "Temp File:" . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/home6/schne.../public_html/FileStore/Data/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);


        $fileResult .= "File Uploaded";
    }

    echo $fileResult;


?>
```

Comment: It does not matter to PHP where you run its scripts, as long as it is hosted somewhere. My guess, from where you are uploading the files -- directory wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem isn't server-side, there's two places to easily go wrong.

You may have forgotten then `enctype` attribute in your form.  Your upload form should look like this:

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Also, make sure you have a `MAX_FILE_SIZE` submitted in the `$_POST` array:

```
<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='100000' />
```

Comment: Do you have the max file size one too?

Comment: Wait, this was the issue actually, I had
enctype='multipart/form_data' 
rather than 
enctype='multipart/form-data'

Comment: Oooh wow that's tricky.  I could have sworn they were identical.  Had to use my "Where's Waldo" skills to find the difference.  Anyway, that's good. Welcome to SO and the community appreciates resolved answers. ;)

Comment: Also, the HTML in the OP is the correct version, apparently, that's a little misleading for future readers...